# How can I get Xamarin StackLayout to allocate height properly to visual elements which use Scaling?

Tags: android, xamarin, height, scaling

I am working in Xamarin, and I need to display a stacklayout with objects within it.  So far so good.  Xamarin correctly places each element above the next, separating them by the padding value.

However, it is also important that I use the 'Scaling' property of some of these elements.  I have to give these elements .5 or .3 or other floats as Scaling values in order to make them smaller.

Scaling works fine.  The objects shrink as you would expect.

The crux of the problem is that the stackLayout does not shrink the space that it has allocated to take into account that the elements are scaled.

If I put 3 boxviews in a stacklayout, and scale the second one to .5 using the Scaling property, then what I want is a normal sized boxview, then a smaller boxview and finally another normal sized boxview, each seperated from the next by the stacklayout's padding.

What I get, however, is a normal sized boxview, then a small boxviewe in the same area that a normal sized boxview receives, followed by another normal sized boxview.

There is a lot of empty space around the scaled down boxview where the stacklayout has allocated sufficient space for its original size.  I don't want that.  I want the stacklayout to give objects the space that they need for their scaled sizes, not their original size.

Does anyone know a way that I can get that to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `<Grid/>`with `<RowDefinitions Height="Auto"/>` instead of using a StackLayout because I've noticed in some cases on more complicated screens StackLayout wouldn't always size/position correctly and I'd have to replace it with a grid.

Also, you could try setting `Spacing="0"` on your StackLayout because spacing by default is set to some value which might by why you're seeing the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the scaling occurs after the element has already been measured and allocated space in the layout.  The real way to achieve the results you want are to bind WidthRequest and HeightRequest to properties in your view model and simply define two sets of properties one for your normal sized box and one for your half size box.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="Root">
    <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Vertical">
        <BoxView HeightRequest="{Binding NormalSize}" WidthRequest="{Binding NormalSize}" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="{Binding HalfSize}" WidthRequest="{Binding HalfSize}" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="{Binding NormalSize}" WidthRequest="{Binding NormalSize}" />
    </BoxView>
</ContentPage>
```

Then in your ViewModel class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public double NormalSize { get { return 40; } }
    public double HalfSize { get { return NormalSize / 2; } }
}
```

Of course any logic can be used to calculate the sizes.  I tend to place view-only stuff like this in the actual Page code behind (i.e. MyPage.xaml.cs file) and bind to it using ElementName to target the root element (your Page class) like so:

```
<BoxView HeightRequest="{Binding NormalSize, ElementName=Root}" ... />
```